# What is the difference between the gens and humans in Dark Metropolis?

Tags: dark-metropolis

In the introduction it said they were a generic race but with superior DNA. They were to be used as a disposable army for a future war (that never came). Well it did in that they went to war with the humans.

In other stories like this the modified race usually has changes that fit the reason they were created. Such as, if it was an army race the emotions would be removed, the reaction time decreased, they don't need as much sleep, etc etc. This type of information is what I'm asking about in this story. The only thing I've picked up so far is that they have a better immune system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [review](http://voices.yahoo.com/dark-metropolis-thrilling-science-fiction-movie-7235250.html) of the film (be warned: it contains spoilers), the Ghens are superior to humans in every way.
Therefore, they must be faster, stronger, smarter etc than humans.